# <f:validateRequired> is invoked after <f:validator>, it should be before

Tags: validation, tomcat, jsf-2

I read that there is no differences between `<f:validateRequired>` and component attribute `required`, [like here](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/f/validateRequired.html):

> A validator that enforces the presence of a value. It has the same affect as setting the required attribute on a UIInput to true.

For some reason, I don't even know why, one of my colleagues changed `required` attribute to the `<f:validateRequired>` tag and it had some negative effetcs.

Here is all of the code (it has many other stuff but maybe it matters and I think it's clear)

```
<h:inputText value="#{value}" id="#{id}" label="#{label}"
    converterMessage="#{msg['validation.digitOnly']}"
    styleClass="#{not component.valid ? invalidStyle : styleClass}"
    maxlength="#{empty maxLength ? validationProperties['validation.long.maxLenght'] : maxLength}">
    <f:converter converterId="intNumberConverter" />
    <f:validateRequired disabled="#{!required}" />
    <f:validateLength maximum="#{maxLength}" disabled="#{empty maxLength}" />
    <f:validator validatorId="#{validatorId}" />
    <f:attribute name="validation.bean" value="#{bean}" />

    <!-- validationProperties is a resource-bundle
            msg is a message-bundle

</h:inputText>
```

When we were using the `required` attribute, an ajax validation of empty field went first and our `uniquenessValidator` (called by `#{validatorId}`) haven't been fired at all, validations stop immediately when `required` validation has failed. Now, our validator goes first and it fail by exception because we assumed that the field is non-empty. I know it is a mistake to assume that in validator! But I'll be more then glad to know why effects are different when on every step I'm being convinced that both ways are identical. That makes them different? Is it recommended to use attribute over the tag and why?

I'm using

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

on Tomcat 7.0.47 with Mojarra. If more config info is required I'll glad to share them.

---

I read some info that `<f:validateRequired>` has problems on Tomcat, but with `VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` I think this isn't this kind of problem.

---

In answer to @BalusC ask. This code is used as a type of general input text field with validation (template).

```
<!-- intNumberInput.xhtml-->
<ui:composition>
    <rich:panel styleClass="#{styleClass}Panel inputWrapperPanel">
        <ui:param name="validatedInputId"
            value="#{(validatedComponentId == null || !bean.notValid) ? id : validatedComponentId}" />

        <c:if test="#{(not empty validatorId) and validatedComponentId == null}">
            <!-- inputText as above, but without label, converters ect. -->
            <h:inputText value="#{value}" id="#{id}">   
                <f:validateRequired disabled="#{!required}" />
                <f:validateLength maximum="#{maxLength}" disabled="#{empty maxLength}" />
                <f:validator validatorId="#{validatorId}" />
                <f:attribute name="validation.bean" value="#{bean}" />
            </h:inputText>
        </c:if>

        <!--  (...) here goes other options -->
</rich:panel>
```

And in real form it goes like this (I had to change some non-english names to make it more readable):

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{installmentBean.installments}" var="payment"
    rowKeyVar="subtable">

    <rich:collapsibleSubTable value="#{payment.installment}" var="installment" expandMode="client" rowKeyVar="row">

    <ui:param name="newRow"
        value="#{installmentBean.newInstallmentIndex == row
                and installmentBean.indeksEdytowanejTabeli == subtable}" />

    <rich:column>
        <!-- NUMBER -->
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{not newRow}">
            <h:outputText value="#{installment.installmentPK.number}" />
        </ui:fragment>
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{newRow}">
            <ui:include src="/common/input/validation/intNumberInput.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="id" value="installmentNumberEdit" />
                <ui:param name="value" value="#{installmentBean.newObject.installmentPK.number}" />
                <ui:param name="required" value="#{true}" />
                <!-- maxlen.installment.number=18-->
                <ui:param name="maxLength" value="#{validationProperties['maxlen.installment.number']}" />
                <ui:param name="bean" value="#{installmentBean}" />
                <ui:param name="validatorId" value="uniquenessValidator" />
            </ui:include>
        </ui:fragment>
    </rich:column>

    <!-- other columns -->

    </rich:collapsibleSubTable>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/validateRequired.html) this tag and the `required` attribute are synonyms. So different behaviour should be taken as a bug in your jsf implementation or a problem/conflict with your specific environment. Which JSF implementation version are you dealing with?

Comment: I have Mojarra v2.1.22 jsf api/impl defined in my pom.xml.

Comment: `<f:validateRequired/>` has indeed exactly the same effect as `required="true"`, however `<f:validateRequired disabled="#{!bean.prop}"/>` hasn't necessarily the same effect as `required="#{bean.prop}"`, depending on how/when/where those vars are definied. Before explaining and answering this, first some more context, preferably in flavor of an SSCCE (there's pretty a lot of irrelevant noise in the small code snippet posted so far ...) would be helpful in pointing out the mistake and providing a true solution.

Comment: I've added more code. `required` is a const. ui:param (`<ui:param name="required" value="#{true}" />`)

Comment: @BalusC, I've changed my question. I know it's not a full SSCCE, but I've cleared the code from styleClasses ect. Most crucial information is that the only thing getting from bean is value, all other things are hardcoded (eg: required) oraz getting from resource-bundle (eg: maxLength). So in `<f:validateRequired disabled="#{!bean.prop}"/>`the `bean.prop` is not exacly a bean property.

I don't want to put more code (such as java bean) not because this is some kind of secret or something, but because I think more code will make it less clear. But if you want more, please, just say so;-)